# What css style to use to render a table inside some text

Tags: html, css

So, I have some text like:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
```

And I want to inject some tables inside this text. Something like:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
<table border="1"><tr><td>Hello world</td></tr></table> 
consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
```

I tried various css styles, like `float`, but did not managed to make it work - the table is either fixed to the left, to the right or to a new line. Hope someone can advise what to do.

Comment: Basically, you can't. That's how tables work. It's really not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Jacobian, Please provide a fiddle for the above example. That would help us understand your question better.

Comment: Do you really want a table or do you want some text with a border around it? (1x1 tables are a good indication that you shouldn't be using a table at all, but it is hard to tell if you are just using poor sample data or poor markup)

Comment: @GaneshBabu.T.Y — Stackoverflow has supported [live inline examples](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for over a year. There's no need to point people to third party hosting.

Comment: I have never used fiddles, but I hope the task is too simple for a fiddle.

Comment: A sketch may be helpful.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vxyro851/1/  This would help you

Comment: @Ganesh Babu. Thank you! It seems like Streetlamp provided the solution. It works

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to inline the table:

```
table {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I will check it in a second. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah! That works absolutely great! Thank you, sir! +100500

Comment: @Jacobian Select this answer as correct one, so that it would help others in future

Comment: @Ganesh Babu I will do that, as soon as stackoverflow allows me - I should wait 8 minutes or so.